# Mysql - optimal indexing for query using IN operator

Tags: mysql, index, index-tuning

I have this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE foo IN (1,2,3,4) AND bar = 123;
```

I have 3 indices:

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD INDEX IDX_foo (foo);

ALTER TABLE table1 ADD INDEX IDX_bar (bar);

ALTER TABLE table1 ADD INDEX IDX_foo_bar (foo, bar);
```

When I try `EXPLAIN` with the query, `IDX_bar` is chosen which I don't understand why. So my questions are:

- Why is `IDX_bar` chosen but not `IDX_foo` or `IDX_foo_bar`?
- Does MySQL choose index differently depend on the data at the time?
- Should I only have `IDX_bar` and remove the other two?

Comment: Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50673201/mysql-optimal-indexing-for-query-using-in-operator

Answer (score 1):

The best index in case above seems to be

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD INDEX IDX_bar_foo (bar,foo);
```

> Why is IDX_bar chosen but not IDX_foo or IDX_foo_bar?

What index will be used and will some index be used at all, is dependent by table statistic (and query text, of course).

Maybe in Your case the index `IDX_bar` is more selective than another 2 indexes.

> Does MySQL choose index differently depend on the data at the time?

That's right. Change data changes statistic and so index choose can change too.

> Should I only have IDX_bar and remove the other two?

For optimizing the query You show - yes (if data stat will not change radically). Or remove all 3 indexes and create index shown above.